# FX Portfolio Volatility Targeting

Tags: volatility, portfolio

If I have 3 different currency trades (ex short EURSEK, short NZDUSD, long USDJPY), how do I size each trade if I wish to allocate risk equally in order to target a 12% portfolio volatility (allowing for leverage and short selling)?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, along with R or python code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for each of the 3 currencies taken separately, find out the leverage $\lambda_i$ ($i=1,2,3$) that would be required to produce an annual standard deviation of $12\%$. [In my experience the std dev of currencies is about $8\%$ or $10\%$, so the three $\lambda$'s will be small, like $1.25$ or $1.2$].

Then find out what is the volatility that results when the three $12\%$ vol currency positions are combined equally into a portfolio. Because of diversification it will not be quite $12\%$, so adjust the three $\lambda$'s proportionately to bring it to the desired $12\%$.

I visualize this as a spreadsheet with separate columns for the historical returns of the different currencies, plus another column for the portfolio; but then I am an Exhell addict ;)